Error Not authorized. check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'
We are having issues on the Sonarqube Stage in Jenkins Pipeline.
We are Getting this error below.

[Sonarqube] > Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.

Here is our code below
This code is working using sonar.login:
export SONAR_TOKEN="Our sonar token"
/apps/installers/gradle-8.5/bin/gradle sonar -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN --stacktrace
echo "Execution of Sonarqube is done"

But after changing it to sonar.token we are getting Not Authorized issue.
export SONAR_TOKEN="Our sonar token"
/apps/installers/gradle-8.5/bin/gradle sonar -Dsonar.token=$SONAR_TOKEN --stacktrace
echo "Execution of Sonarqube is done"

